# Setting Custom headers in the Response of Rails Application is good practice or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, http-headers, httpresponse

I want to send the country-specific data in some API request from the client side. This data will remain same throughout the user session. Is it good practice to set the custom headers in response as follows:

```
response.header['Custom-Header-Name'] = 'Custom-Header-Value'
```

Comment: its Depends, its depends on your Application, Logic, Flow....and so on

Comment: During networking does the response headers change due to any middlewares? Do headers gets affected due to proxies?

Comment: Be specific, If you are looking for `During networking does the response headers change due to any middlewares? Do headers gets affected due to proxies? `  then you need to specify all aspect that you are looking.

Comment: I am setting 'Iso-Code' in response headers, which seems very generic key. It may happen that some middlewares using the same key during processing particular request, and may alter the value. should I use a specific scope? like setting key as 'My-Custom-key' and value as { iso-code: 'USD'}.

Comment: Use Secure Headers, look at the blog you will get some more idea of header `https://blog.appcanary.com/2017/http-security-headers.html`